# Is there a better way than dangerouslySetInnerHTML to encode HTML entities / code with React?

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm creating a React app that fetches all its content by making requests to an API server. After doing some research I've discovered that, in the case that the JSON response sent by the API includes HTML entities or tags, I can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to format the response, doing something like this:

```
class SinglePage extends React.Component {  

    render() {        

        const post = this.props.selectedPost

        return(
            <div id="page" className="single-page layout sb-content-sb">    
                <main id="content" className="column has-padding-top">      
                    <article id="article">
                        <h1>{ post.data.title.rendered }</h1>
                        <div className="editor" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: post.data.content.rendered } } />
                    </article>
                </main>               
            </div>
        );

    }

}
```

This works, but it feels so weird... Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Not that the dupetarget has much in the way of useful answers. Hopefully your question will inspire more.